# Make input box width smaller when browser is zoomed with css only

Tags: html, css, input, zooming

I want to make my input box width get smaller something more like reduced width, when the browser is zoomed out, and wider when the browser is zoomed in, cause my content is overlapping.

When i zoom out my content starts to overlap. The first image is 100% percent zoom, browser default.

[image: Normal 100% zoom]

When I zoom to 110%

[image: 110% zoom, content nearly enters the search bar]

When i zoom to 125%

[image: 125% zoom, content enters the search bar]

How do I make the search bar reduce on zoom out 100% - 110%, and make it increase on zoom in 125% zoom -> 100% zoom

What I have tried.

```
<div class="example-navigation-bar-two">
   <input type="text" class="example-navigation-bar-two-input"   placeholder="Search any food item on Example...">
</div>
```

AND my css

```
.example-navigation-bar-two{
  width:68%;    
}   
.example-navigation-bar-two-input{
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  float: none;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #fff;
  border-top: 1px solid #f3f3f3;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #f3f3f3;
  border-left:0px;
  border-right:0px;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding-top:3px;
  padding-left:5px;
  padding-right:5px;
  width:100%;
  height:31.2px;
}
```

LOGIN/REGISTER HTML

```
<div class="sharyor-navigation-bar-two">
  <div class="sharyor-hundred-percent">
    
    <div class="sharyor-right-one">
      <a href="">
        <div><i class="fa fa-user-o"></i></div>
        <span>Login/Register</span>
      </a>
    </div>
    
    <div class="sharyor-right-two">
      <a href="">
        <div><i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i></div>
        <span>Wish to buy</span>
      </a>
    </div>
    
    <div class="sharyor-right-three">
      <a href="">
        <div><i class="fa fa-shopping-basket"></i></div>
        <span>Cart</span>
      </a>
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

LOGIN/REGISTER CSS

```
.sharyor-navigation-bar-two{
  z-index:1000;
  right:0;
  margin-right:15px;  
  display:flex;
  position:absolute;
}
.sharyor-hundred-percent{
  width:100%;
  position:relative;
  display:flex;
}
.sharyor-right-one{
  padding-right:20px; 
}
.sharyor-right-two{
  padding-right:20px; 
}
.sharyor-right-three{
  padding-right:15px; 
}
```

Comment: Can you add some more html showing **login/register** etc text and their styling?

Comment: @DebsmitaPaul Okay

Comment: @DebsmitaPaul Done the edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your login/register styling has no relative sizes, you can use `@media` to change the size based on the size of the viewport. This will work disregarding the maximum viewport size.

```
@media screen and (width < 800px){
   .example-navigation-bar-two-input{
       /* change size here */
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to the accepted answer above, this should capture 110%, 125% and 150% ZOOM.

```
@media (max-width: 1300px) {
.example-navigation-bar-two-input{{
width:62%;  
}
}
@media (max-width: 1100px) {
.example-navigation-bar-two-input{{
width:51%;  
}
}
@media (max-width: 1000px) {
.example-navigation-bar-two-input{{
width:30%;  
}
}
```